# How to access terraform input variables using import

Tags: terraform, terraform-import

I'm trying to use the terraform import flow with input variables, like this:

`terraform import -var-file=values.tfvars.json ADDR ID`

According to what I read the flow goes throught the import function and the read function.
It seems that I can not access the values that was passed usig the `-var-file` property in neither one of those functions (import\read).

Is it possible to do so?
if not, I would expect this command to ignore the required values of this solution.

Comment: Usually for every resource there is a set of required arguments. You can initially hardcode them and then later on switch to using variables.

Comment: I don't get them in the read\import functions. I don't want to hardcode them. I want to use -var-file param

Comment: That is why I said initially. When they are in the state you can fall back to using the variables.

Comment: the state file is created each time for scratch, I can't rely on the funct that the state file exists

Comment: Uhm, why is it created from scratch **every** time?

Comment: because this is done in a pod and is destroyed after the reuest is handled

Comment: That is really really a bad idea. You can use remote backend and you will not have to do that each time.

Comment: why is it a bad idea?
It's a bad I idea for me to maintain a DB of states.. each change of the entities I need to update the states... I prefere to create each time a new state file rather than maintain a DB of states

Comment: Because that is not how terraform is supposed to be used. It should have a persistent state file rather then deleting it and then recrating it using import over and over again. State file is literally why terraform has advantage over other similar tools. If you don't need the state to persist, then you might as well use Ansible or another IaC tool.